# Restrict label size from theme CSS in GTK?

Tags: css, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to create themes for a [program](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/notifyd/4.14/theming) for GNOME that uses [GtkLabel](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html) in a widget. I see that GTK Label already has a function for constraining the maximum length of a label, similar to the standard CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis`. GTK uses _ellipsize and max-width-chars.

However, I need to access these properties EXCLUSIVELY from my gtk.css, without changing the source code of the program. I don't even need to use these properties directly, I just want to take advantage of the fact that GTK already has that capability. If there's an indirect way of using them (i.e.: using Pango attributes somehow...), it works.

Here's the source of the program I'm using: https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-notifyd/-/blob/master/xfce4-notifyd/xfce-notify-daemon.c

The part of the GTK code I believe to be relevant: https://code.woboq.org/gtk/gtk/gtk/gtklabel.c.html

I've only been able to find documentation about how to implement Ellipsize in HTML, python, etc. I haven't found a way to use it from CSS.

Is it possible to do this, or should I just try a different program?